# I was so confused about window size in Kivy

Tags: kivy, set, window, size, textinput

In Kivy, I set the window size to (400, 600) by calling `Config.set()`, it goes well. When I imported the TextInput widget, the window size was reset back to (800, 600).

I am so confused - what happened?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
#from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '600')

class TestPage(RelativeLayout):
    pass

class TestPageApp(App):
    def build(self):
        home = TestPage()
        label = Label(text='Hello World')
        home.add_widget(label)
        return home

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestPageApp().run()
```